# How to show names of attachments from a list item in a column?

Tags: list, list-item, attachments, multiline-text-field

I have an announcements list and some announcements have multiple attachments. The view is set to show the attachments, but it just shows this paperclip icon which probably means the list item has attachments.

What I need to achieve, is to show the name of the attachments of the list items in an extra column (if possible, on a multiline text field). How would I achieve this?

I found [this](http://amitphule.blogspot.be/2012/04/display-item-attachments-in-sharepoint.html) site that has an answer but it is for SP2010, I am working in SP2013 and I can't use this. :( Anything that can be done with SP Designer 2013 would be awesome.

Comment: why you said you can't use what the site you linked suggested? You can still manually edit the xslt code

Comment: I do not know how to manually edit the xslt code, I see something completely different than in the site I suggested. I don't see xsl elements.

Comment: because you have to click on "customize xslt". see here http://anklal7.blogspot.it/2013/05/customize-list-view-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: But I can't! Even in advanced mode, wherever I click in the code of the list view, I never get the "List view tools" tab in my SPD2013 ribbon, all I get is the "Code view tools", "Web part tools" and "web part zone tools" tabs. The problem I have is like the one here: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/177765/523087.aspx

Comment: In the link you gave, there is a workaround for your issue. Tried it?

Comment: I did try it, but still no list view tools.

Comment: without being able to customize the XSLT, there isn't much you can do. I would first try to fix the missing list view tools tab

Comment: are can modify the XSL and the jquery to show the attachments

Comment: Use XSl and Jquery for this
[Follow it](http://sympmarc.com/2010/05/26/using-sharepointattachmentsfield-in-a-dvwps-xsl/)

Comment: we have this problem and no total solution exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do it.

One is create a hidden field in the list named Attachments, and with the help of event receiver, set it when attachment added, updated, deleted. So, now you have the attachment names (if needed add them as links, for this the column must be of type multi line text box (rich text field)).

Second and easiest way is the modifications using SharePoint Designer. Just follow this steps mentioned at: http://amitphule.blogspot.in/2012/04/display-item-attachments-in-sharepoint.html

Let me know if you need any additional help.

Comment: Will the second way also work when a list item has more than one attachment? So if a list item has two attachments, will it be able to show the names of both attachments or will it only show the name of the first attachment?

Comment: with those event receiver you can download and upload to another document library and set value hyperlink for that docs in the custom field that you can develop that if you want @Magali

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already found a solution for your issue. I was also struggling with the issue similar to yours. Could not get "List view tools" for my view. That was resolved after I checked "Server Render" option in Web Part properties-Miscellaneous section. However, I found an easy workaround by using jslink and jquery. Please refer to [this source.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74dac191-5a9e-4970-a9f6-a501846f0bef/forum-faq-show-attachments-in-sharepoint-2013-custom-list-view?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

I got round this issue by using Infopath Designer to inject the URL into a "simple line of text" field.

The steps were as follows.

1. create a "single line of text" field in your list. I called mine "AttachmentURL"

[image: Add a single line of text field]

2. Load infopath designer. and load your SharePoint list
3. Right click on the "single line of text" field "AttachmentURL" and select "Text box properties"

[image: Select text box properties]

4. In the "Default Value" section next to "Value", click the "Fx" button

[image: Fx]

5. In the "Formula" dialog box, select the "Insert Field or Group" button

[image: Insert field or group]

6. In "Advanced view", expand the "Attachments" folder, and select the ":attachmentURL" icon and click "OK" all the way back to your form

[image: Select field or group]

7. After making any other alterations in your form, publish the form to the SharePoint list

[image: Publish]

This gave me the attachment filename. I then used SharePoint Designer to build the rest of the URL :

8. Open SharePoint Designer and go to your list workflow
9. You will now be able to build the Attachment's URL by creating a hyperlink that follows this construction :

   https://site/Forms/Lists/LISTNAME/Attachments/ID/AttachmentURL

[image: Create hyperlink in designer]

I had no issue creating the attachment URL in a designer workflow with this method. You can then push the full URL to another field if you like, or email it with the workflow.

[image]